# Customized data in serenity report

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am trying to add version information which is displayed in the login page to the serenity report index.html.
The version information is captured in LoginPage.java. I see that I can use @Step method to include customized statements in the report.
Can someone please give me some details on how to use the @Step feature to include the message in index.html?
I am just starting to use serenity-bdd framework, So any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this:

```
String first = "param1";
String second = "param2";

@Step("Test step with parameters: {0} and {1}.")
public void testStep(String first, String second)
// method body...
```

Report will display it as:

**Test step with parameters: param1 and param2.**

Otherwise, if you don't provide the {0} and {1}, it will look like this:

```
String first = "param1";
String second = "param2";

@Step("Test step with parameters")
public void testStep(String first, String second)
// method body...
```

**Test step with parameters: param1, param2**

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following statement to print version information in the report:

```
String version = "3.4.12";
Serenity.recordReportData().withTitle("Version").andContents(version);
```